# Count variable isn't increasing as the program iterates like it should --in program that counts numbers with repeating digits

Tags: c++, loops, boolean

I am working on a program that goes through a vector of consecutive numbers and identifies the numbers that have repeating digits. The output should remove these "invalid" numbers with repeating digits and output the amount of remaining "valid" numbers with no repeating digits within the range a and b that defines the vector.

My variable count keeps track of how many numbers in the vector have repeating digits. between the numbers 8 and 12, for example there should be 1 invalid number (being 11). my count variable outputs as 0 for almost everything. (my functions used are in a separate file).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "functions.h"


int main() {
    //variables
    int a, b, i, count = 0; // a & b inputs, i for iterating
    int x = 0;  //variable for digit occurrence count

    //entering number range
    std::cout << "Enter numbers 0 < a <= b <= 10000: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;

    //making a vector to contain numbers between a and b
    std::vector<int> listofnums((b-a)+1); 
    int initialvalue = a;
    while (i <= (b-a)) {  
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 


        //call the has repeating digits function
        has_repeating_digits(listofnums[i]);
        if (has_repeating_digits(listofnums[i]) == true) {  //counting nums w repeat digits
            count++;
        }

        //call the count digit occurrences function
        count_digit_occurrences(listofnums[i], x);

        initialvalue++; 
        i++; 
    }

    //Call the valid range function
    range_is_valid(a, b);
    if (range_is_valid(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "The range is invalid" << std::endl;
    }

    //call the count valid numbers function
    std::cout << count ;
    std::cout << "There are " << count_valid_numbers(a, b, count);
    std::cout << " valid numbers between " << a << " and " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `i`.

Comment: it is set equal to 0 at the top and then within the loop there is an i++  - I'm confused @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Only `count` and `x` are assigned to `0`. Change your code to `int a = 0, b = 0, i = 0, count = 0;`. You should also check if `0 < a <= b <= 10000` before creating the vector and proceeding to the loop.

Comment: use a debugger to test your theory about how code works. walk the code and you will see.

Comment: You can skip the current `i` declaration and turn the `while` loop into a `for` loop instead: `for(int i = 0; i <= (b-a); ++i) { ...`

Comment: @SaraMillan "*[i] is set equal to 0 at the top*" - this code does not ENSURE `i` starts at 0.  Initialize it to 0 explicitly.  Also, why are you calling `has_repeating_digits()` twice per loop iteration, and calling `range_is_valid()` twice AFTER the loop is finished? Why aren't you calling `range_is_valid()` BEFORE entering your loop? Also, how is `count_digit_occurrences()` declared, and where is `x` being used?

Comment: @JonnyHenly you're right I fixed it - I'm very very new to this apologies for the very obvious mistakes

Comment: @SaraMillan You forgot the increment  listofnums[i] = initialvalue++;  :)

Comment: They're only very obvious mistakes because we've been doing it for a long time. They're probably mistakes we made once upon a time. One of the advantages of using `auto` is that you HAVE to initialise your values